# Unsupported Graphics Card

Tags: 14.04, ati, graphics, fglrx

I have Ubuntu 14.04 on my Intel 3rd Gen Core i7 system having ATI Radeon HD 7670M
I downloaded the latest AMD Graphics Driver from AMD website (i.e. Version 14.9). After running it as SU and pressing Next it gave me an error which said

```
Your graphics adapter is not supported by this driver. Installation will not proceed.
```

I wanted to know what can I do to solve this problem??

Comment: This is not a question.

Answer (score 0):

> "Your graphics adapter is not supported by this driver. Installation will not proceed."

That reads to me like you downloaded the incorrect driver.  You may want to check what you downloaded.

Also, did you check the System Settings -> Software and Updates -> Additional Drivers tab to see if Ubuntu already has some drivers for you?

Comment: I am sorry but I checked the driver for windows with same version number and it was working also I downloaded it from AMD's website where it was clearly mentioned that it was for my graphics series and OS